# MongoDB conditional (sum if exists, else zero)

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, ifnull

I am trying to sum across a field within an aggregate pipeline where the field may not exist. Otherwise, the return should be zero. This is my code so far:

```
admits = [
    {'$match': {'meta.State': item['state'],'meta.County': item['county'], 'meta.first_seen': date}},
    {'$group': {'_id': {'item': '$item'}, 'admissions': {'$ifNull': [{'$sum': 1}, 0]}}},
]
```

This does not work, because calling `$sum` within an `$ifNull` raises a unary operator exception:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The $ifNull accumulator is a unary operator
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The $ifNull accumulator is a unary operator*

The `<accumulator>` operator must be one of the following accumulator operators: [accumulator-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator), and `$ifNull` operator is not one of them,

The `$sum` operator must be in root if you want to sum,

The usage of [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) is:

> Evaluates an expression and returns the value of the expression if the expression evaluates to a non-null value. If the expression evaluates to a null value, including instances of undefined values or missing fields, returns the value of the replacement expression.

So `$ifNull` will not fulfil your requirement,

You can try [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to check if field type is missing then then 0 otherwise 1,

```
{
  '$group': {
    '_id': {'item': '$item'}, 
    'admissions': {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$admissions" }, "missing"] }, 0, 1]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure this achieves 0s in output...

[{'_id': {'item': None}, 'admissions': 3}]
[{'_id': {'item': None}, 'admissions': 4}]
[]
[{'_id': {'item': None}, 'admissions': 7}]
[{'_id': {'item': None}, 'admissions': 5}] <-- on the date with zero admissions, it returns an empty list

Comment: For a given date t, there may be no documents with meta.first_seen: t

Comment: This is perhaps not the cleanest fix, but I can just try-except on the aggregation return, and insert a 0 if it's an empty list...

Comment: can you show updated post. if it does not resolve then can you please add some document in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) and share link.